# Subconscious divide?

Tags: phrase-meaning, nouns

I can't get a good definition of this word:

> There are some countries that have a **subconscious divide** in terms of social status.

I think this pertains to social discrimination but they don't say it in so many words/directly to you, as something that categorizes people. **Is this correct/ does this word exist?**

Comment: John, You seem to pluck sentences out of the air or write them, and they have mistakes. Then, you ask a vocabulary question about a word and actually post two words in bold. If the sentence is found, please tell  us where. If you are writing it, please tell us. The sentence is not grammatical but that is not related to the phrase: subconscious divide at all.

Comment: I'm just making a query out of this, but it seems it's not a word, phrase, or even anything at all. It sounds good cause it shortens the description of how social status is divided by categories by wealth or the like, as I've been planning to use it later. Anyway, I won't, I just heard from a non-native speaker who lives in an english-speaking country. Thx still.

Comment: @JohnArvin - Something like "I just heard this from a non-native speaker who lives in an English-speaking country" is helpful information. You should include that sort of thing in your future questions.

Comment: Tnx, got it, I will next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phrase

> **subconscious divide**

refers to a division, usually social, that is unspoken but is usually well practiced as the customary behaviour.

Comment: Oh so this really exists. Very well then, I'll use this but be extremely cautious.